# Find correct URL using python modules

Tags: python

We were given a URL, lets say https://www.123.com/random4digitnumber. (example, https://www.123.com/1234) Using python, we have to find that 4 digit number to find the right URL. I have to use python 3.7.

I have tried importing webbrowser and making a loop where i open every page from 0000 to 9999, but it is very time consuming.

EDIT: apologies, i forgot to add a crucial detail. I have added it in.

My ideal output would be the 4 digit number that is of the correct URL, or the correct URL itself. Thanks a lot.

Comment: please mention more details.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to StackOverflow. Please edit your question and provide more details about your issue. What code did you try? What output do you expect using what input? Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Can you show what have you tried and elaborate more on your question.

Comment: I have added more details, sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get your question correctly. Try below solution, I think you need this kind of solution.

```py
import requests

for i in range(0, 10000):
    url = f'https://www.123.com/{"{:04}".format(i)}'
    response = requests.get(url, verify=False)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        print(f'correct url is : {url}')
        break
```

I added `verify=False` because the https://www.123.com/ site use the [Self-signed certificate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-signed_certificate). You'll get `404` as the output, which mean the given URL not found.

Comment: I will try to clarify further. It is not 123.com, but another url i cannot specify. the url can be from 123.com/0000 to 123.com/9999. I need to find the right one. i will try your code now

Comment: @user11679375 check the solution now, I updated it. Now it's looping 0000 to 9999 and will return the correct URL you want if found any.

Answer (score 0):

all you need to do is create a list of all links and then try to hit those links,
and check the status of the response. if status is less than 400 then they are valid.

below is sample code

```
import requests

k=[]
for i in range(0,10):
    for j in range(0,10):
        for l in range(0,10):
            for m in range(0,10):
                st ='https://www.123.com/' +str(i)+str(j)+str(l)+str(m)
                k.append(st)
res = []
for v,i in enumerate(k):
    try:
        print(v)
        if requests.get(i).status_code<400:
            res.append(i)
            print('{} is valid link'.format(i))
    except:
        print('{} is not valid link'.format(i))
        pass
```